# Point estimators

Tags: statistics

I hope someone can point me in the right direction with this:

If I have $X(1), X(2), X(3), X(4)$ taken from a population with a mean $\mu$ and a variance $\sigma^2$, how do I show that $\hat \mu= X(1)$ is an unbiased estimator, assuming I'm right in that just one element of a sample has 0 variance?

Thanks,

Comment: To show $\hat \mu$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$ you need to show $E[\hat \mu\mid\mu]=\mu$. It is rather obvious in this case and has nothing to do with the variance of the population or of the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X_1,X_2,...,X_4$ is a random sample, the distribution of each $X_i$ is equal with the distribution of the population which also implies that:
$$E[X_i]=E[X]=\mu$$

We can conclude that each $X_i$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$

Note:
An estimator of $\theta$ is an unbiased estimator if $E[\hat{\theta}]=\theta$.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.